# Saving and loading simple data in Python convenient way

Tags: python, python-3.x, save, persistence

I'm currently working on a simple Python 3.4.3 and Tkinter game.

*I struggle with saving/reading data now, because I'm a beginner at coding.*

What I do now is use .txt files to store my data, but I find this extremely counter-intuitive, as saving/reading more than one line of data requires of me to have additional code to catch any newlines.

Skipping a line would be terrible too.

I've googled it, but I either find .txt save/file options or way too complex ones for saving large-scale data.

I only need to save some strings right now and be able to access them (if possible) by key like in a dictionary key:value .

Do you know of any file format/method to help me accomplish that?

**Also: *If possible, should work on Win/iOS/Linux.***

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like using [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) would be best for this, which comes as part of the [Python Standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/index.html) in Python-2.6+

```
import json

data = {'username':'John', 'health':98, 'weapon':'warhammer'}

# serialize the data to user-data.txt
with open('user-data.txt', 'w') as fobj:
    json.dump(data, fobj)

# read the data back in
with open('user-data.txt', 'r') as fobj:
    data = json.load(fobj)

print(data)
# outputs: 
# {u'username': u'John', u'weapon': u'warhammer', u'health': 98}
```

A popular alternative is [`yaml`](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation), which is actually a superset of json and produces slightly more human readable results.

Comment: It seems to be a good solution, unfortunately when I run the first half of your code, it throws a `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`

Comment: oops, yeah sorry the 'binary' mode causes issues in python-3 because it's expecting `string`s to be properly encoded. The fix is to remove the `b`.  Will update the answer

Comment: @xXthruXx, should work now in python3, can you give it another try?

Comment: Works like a charm :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try Redis.

http://redis.io/

I'm not totally sure it'll meet all your needs, but it would probably be better than a flat file.

Comment: You're not sure if _Redis_ would meet all of OP's needs? I would say Redis is waay overkill for this.

Comment: I've looked through this and it's a sweet tool, but for this project it's too much compared to other, built-in options. Thanks anyway! :)